# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object DateField

Tags: python, django

Estou tendo um problema muito chato no Django para trabalhar com data. Eu estou enviando do meu angular uma data que seleciono em um `input data`. Na minha `view`, eu transformo a data para esse formato: `2017-10-13`

Quando tento fazer update no meu campo DateField, recebo o erro:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Campo na Model:

```
data_resgate = models.DateField('Data Resgate', null=True, blank=True)
```

Como estou fazendo o update:

```
model.data_resgate = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(data.get('data_resgate', None), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z").date())
```

Estou com `USE_L10N = True`.

**@UPDATE**

O pior é, quando eu dou um `python manage.py shell` para fazer o update manualmente, quando eu adiciono a string `2017-10-13`, ele salva corretamente sem dar erro.

**@UPDATE2**

Quando eu apenas pego a data recebida do `input date`, e tento gerar um date com o `datetime`, ele nem chega converter pois recebo a data do input de outra forma.

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: O erro dá em que chamado de métodos mesmo?

Comment: Ele está dando no `save()`. Bem estranho né?

Comment: E se você fizer isso: `model.data_resgate = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(data.get('data_resgate', None)), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z").date())`?

Comment: Eu tentei, mas não funcionou. Estou colocando até uma string mesmo '2017-10-13' e não ta rolando. Acho que tem algo relacionado ao `USE_L10N`, ou devo estar pecando em algum detalhe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ficou um pouco difícil de saber em que momento você está recebendo este erro, tento lhe ajudar reproduzindo o mesmo cenário (com sucesso) com um model chamado Teste, conforme a seguir:

```
data = {'data_resgate': '2017-10-10'}
teste = Teste()
teste.data_resgate = datetime.datetime.strptime(data.get('data_resgate', None), "%Y-%m-%d").date()
teste.save()
```

Perceba que utilizei apenas o formato *%Y-%m-%d*. Uma vez que o campo é somente de data, entendo que não seja necessário trabalhar com informações adicionais relacionadas a horas e minutos ou se preocupar com Time Zone. Não é necessário, inclusive, fazer um cast para *str*, já que o campo é um *DateField*. Certifique-se, ainda, que *data.get('data_resgate', None)* retorna um *str* pois, se retornar outro tipo de dado ou até None (que foi definido como padrão em caso de ausência desta chave), a função *strptime* retornará também um erro.

Se permanecer o erro, poste um stacktrace mais detalhado para podermos identificar melhor o momento e o local em que este erro está ocorrendo. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Eduardo. Editei conforme pedido, mas não é dessa forma que eu recebo a data do `input date`. Ela vem dessa forma: `2017-11-18T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Curioso...fiz o mesmo teste anterior colocando 2017-11-18T00:00:00.000Z no dicionário e %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z no formato e funcionou perfeitamente...A mensagem de erro que você recebe diz justamente que ele só conseguiu fazer o parse até a data...a partir da hora não encontrou mais nada. Tem certeza que o valor que está vindo no dicionário está correto? Verifica se talvez a string não tem caracteres especiais ocultos, como \r ou \n, por exemplo (entre outros). Este dicionário está pegando dados de onde?

Comment: Absoluta certeza.. Como pode ver na pergunta, eu ja tentei inclusive inserir uma data manual, e nada. Não entendo o porque ele não ta funcionando.

Comment: Os forms funcionam perfeitamente.

Comment: Ele da esse alerta no `save()`, porém, se eu removo o update do campo de data, o resto funciona. Então realmente o erro está nesse update de data.

Comment: Fiquei intrigado pelo fato de aqui ter funcionado. Será que podemos ter alguma questão relacionada às versões do python e do django? Se tiver interesse e quiser me passar por email pequenos trechos do seu model, da sua view e do seu template para eu poder simular aqui e lhe ajudar, estou à disposição. Se julgar viável, é claro.

Comment: Então, passar trechos do código é complicado, mas consigo te passar exatamente o que estou fazendo. Resumidamente: de um <input type="data"> estou enviando a data pro django. Antes de testar com a data que recebo, eu ja estou mocando uma data que estou gerando. Nem isso funciona: `minhamodel.data_resgate = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())`.

Comment: Meu campo é um `DateField`: `data_resgate = models.DateField('Data Resgate', null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now().date())`

Comment: Estou com `USE_L10N = True`

Comment: Sem problemas, tenho certeza de que vamos resolver. Vamos lá: quando você faz `minhamodel.data_resgate = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())`, qual dos dois erros citados na pergunta você recebe? O `TypeError` ou o `ValueError`? Tenta também fazer este mesmo teste desta linha sem o cast para str e me avisa os resultados.

Comment: Executei a mesma linha idêntica aqui, com o campo exatamente igual no models e inseriu com sucesso, inclusive com o `USE_L10N = True`. Alguma configuração diferenciada relacionada a datas talvez que você possua no seu settings.py além dessa?

Comment: TypeError. Ele peded string ou byte object. Muito estranho. Também estou achando que não tem nada relacionado ao `USE_L10N`, mas sim na criação do model ou algo no meu banco de dados.

Comment: Tentou sem o cast para str? Dá uma olhada também diretamente no banco e vê qual o tipo de dados que ele criou para esta coluna. Talvez algum problema com as migrações?

Comment: Ja descobri. Eu estava criando um registro porem nao tinha um default para data. E como eu estava permitindo null e blank, estava dando um erro logo no inicio. Foi só adicionar um default `datetime.now()` que funcionou.

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu! Realmente nem passou pela minha cabeça isso. Pensei que o erro que daria para este caso seria bem diferente!